# Система игнорирует файл hosts!

Tags: hosts, windows-xp

В файле hosts пишу:

```
127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com  127.0.0.1 facebook.com
```

Набираю адрес в браузреах Opera и iexplore и вижу страницу фейсбука.
Что я делал:
 1. ipconfig /flushdns 
 2. отключил службу DNS client и сменил тип запуска на "вручную"
 3. отключил все "антивирусные" программы, которые могут редактировать этот файл
 4. проверил путь к файлу hosts в реестре windows.   
 5. выполнял nbtstat -R   
 В чем может быть еще причина?   
Операционная система: Windows XP pro sp 3 LanOS

Comment: Да бы сузить проблему, > ping facebook.comЧто пингует?

Comment: ping facebook.comОбмен пакетами с facebook.com [69.171.237.16] по 32 байт:Ответ от 69.171.237.16: число байт=32 время=186мс TTL=247....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Каждый IP должен идти с новой строки. В вашем примере второй адрес как-бы в роли доменного имени.

А также прочтите замечание в описании hosts на википедии, пункт "Использование при соединении через прокси-сервера"
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts

> Замена IP-адреса на доменное имя, записанное в строке файла hosts, не
>   работает (Windows), если используется соединение через Proxy-Server

Answer (score 0):

Войди под администратором обнови windows. Потом удали файл хостс и создай заново, под своим пользователем.

еще проверь путь к файлу HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parametersи посмотри на наличие в папке скрытого файла